# issue in creating stacked horizontal bar-chart in chartJs

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I need to create a stacked horizontal bar chart and for the below code the chart is coming as horizontal but it is not stacked. I have created a seperate component for chart and using it in another component I gone through few stacked overflow articles but didn't help. I not able to find out the issue. any help is very appreciated.

horizontal-chart.component.ts

```
export class HorizontalBarchartComponent implements OnInit {

dataCtx: any;
bar_chart: any;

@ViewChild('horizontalbarChart') horizontalbarChartRef: ElementRef;
@Input() data = [];
@Input() yLabel: any;
@Input() xLabel: any;
@Input() nameObj?: any;
@Input() stacked:boolean;
@Input() hoverData:Array<any>;

colors: Array<string> = ["rgba(98, 228, 98, 1)", "rgba(248, 227, 117, 1)", "rgba(250, 99,131, 1)"]
constructor() { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.renderChart();
}

ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.horizontalbarChartRef){
    this.renderChart();
  }
}

renderChart() {
  this.dataCtx = this.horizontalbarChartRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

this.bar_chart = new Chart(this.dataCtx, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: this.nameObj.map(obj => obj.name),
    datasets:this.setData()
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        padding: 20,
        fontStyle: 'bold',
        fontSize: 12,
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        position:'top',
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          labelString: this.yLabel
        },
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          beginAtZero: true,
          max:10
        },
        gridLines: {
          display:false,
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        maxBarThickness: 50,
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          fontStyle: 'bold',
          labelString: this.xLabel
        },
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display:false
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
  }
});

}

setData(){
let fixed_options ={
  borderColor: 'transparent',
  borderWidth: 2,
  pointBorderColor: 'transparent',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
  pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
  pointRadius: 3,
  pointHitRadius: 20,
  pointBorderWidth: 1,
}
if(this.stacked){
  let subData = [];
  this.data.filter((d,index) => { subData.push({"data":d, "backgroundColor": this.colors[index],"label": this.hoverData[index], fixed_options }) });
  return subData;
}
else{
  return [{"data": this.data,"backgroundColor":'rgba(98, 228, 98, 1)',"label":`Upload/Sketch's Per Factor Scores`}]
}
```

}
}

another.component.html

```
<horizontal-barchart class="col-md-10" [data]="horizontalBar.data" yLabel="Percentage"
        [xLabel]="'student names'" [nameObj]="quizOrTestAnalysis" [stacked]="true" 
        [hoverData]="['Proficient Answers', 'Elimination Answers', 'Random Answers']"> 
</horizontal-barchart>
```

another.component.ts

```
 horizontalBar = {
data:[[10],[20],[30]],
}
```

The output of the provided code
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had set `ticks:{max:10}` on x:axis which restricting the chart from showing further data